# Difference between Compact database and SQL Server database 

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I was wondering what is the difference between this file when we are talking about deploying the application? So my application don't throw me an error or something like that.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use a MS-SQL (Express) database (mdf files) you will have to install a server on the target computer.

The SQL-CE (sdf) files only require a simple DLL to be shipped with your App.

Answer (score 0):

Sql compact sdf files are good for portable applications, or where no concurrent connections (different clients) need to connect to the same db, very ideal for client stand alone app, or where where sql server is not available to attach mdf files. Moreover, data in sdf files can be encrypted and file password protected, so only your application can unlock and read the file.